# How can I get the count of values from a Neo4j database?

Tags: python, neo4j

I am trying to execute a simple count query with Neo4j in Python. It's returning some sort of Neo4j Bolt object and I want to extract the value of the count.

This is the query I'm using:

```
result = session.run("MATCH (q:Tweet) <-[:LIKE]-(p:Person) WHERE p.Username = $username AND ID(q) = $id RETURN COUNT(q)", username=username, id=TweetkID)
```

Furthermore, I have added these print statements:

```
print(result)
print(result.single())
print((result.single())[0])
```

The output of these print statements follows:

```
<neo4j.BoltStatementResult object at 0x7fa089f36908>
<Record COUNT(q)=2>
```

UPDATE:

```
print((result.single())[0])
```

returns an exception:

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

As you can see, it correctly counts but returns some sort of object instead of just an int.  <strike>Furthermore, `print((result.single())[0])` isn't even printing</strike> .

All I want is the count and it is there. I just don't know how to get it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should print out the count value:

```
print(result.single().value())
```